# psql version does not change to 12 even after upgrade

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

I have acquired an image of postgre sql by doing `docker pull postgres:12`. I intended to build a webpage with Django with this being my database, so i started in this container building Django projects. However, when i ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, I got the following error:

```
    raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.9).
```

but i did pull the image specifying the version to be 12. Regardless, i tried to upgrade my psql. i did `sudo apt-get update`. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12 postgresql-server-dev-12`, and
(in case of any need for closer examination here) the output was

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-12 (12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/12/man/man1/psql.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/psql.1.gz (psql.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.39) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up libclang1-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (214ubuntu0.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Adding user postgres to group ssl-cert

Creating config file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf with new version
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libomp5-10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up postgresql-12 (12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 12/main ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main --auth-local peer --auth-host md5
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/12/main ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Asia/Shanghai
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctlcluster 12 main start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5435 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/12/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up sysstat (12.2.0-2ubuntu0.3) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline

Creating config file /etc/default/sysstat with new version
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/sar.sysstat to provide /usr/bin/sar (sar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/sar.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/sar.sysstat.1.gz (of link group sar) doesn't exist      
Setting up libpopt0:amd64 (1.16-14) ...
Setting up logrotate (3.14.0-4ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libomp-10-dev (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libclang-common-10-dev (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libclang-cpp10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up llvm-10-runtime (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up clang-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up llvm-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up llvm-10-dev (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up postgresql-server-dev-12 (12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.12) ...
```

I went on to do

```bash
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
psql --version
```

and the output was `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.17 (Ubuntu 12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`. great. However, after i stopped the container and restarted it, the version returned to 11.9.

And this time, however i tried repeating what i had done, the version remains 11.9. I did

```bash
postgres@fc141f712f26:~$ cd /usr/lib/postgresql/
postgres@fc141f712f26:/usr/lib/postgresql$ ls
12
```

so there is not even any sign of version 11 left here. Some other outputs of my attempts are:

```bash
sudo apt-get install postgresql-12 postgresql-server-dev-12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-12 is already the newest version (12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
postgresql-server-dev-12 is already the newest version (12.17-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
```

```bash
sudo service postgresql stop
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 12 database server  
             
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start

sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server  

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.9         

postgres@fc141f712f26:/usr/lib/postgresql$ sudo service postgresql status
12/main (port 5435): online
```

As is shown the version remains 11.9. I even examined the `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`, and i didn't see anything wrong. I am now clueless.

*result of doing `pg_lsclusters`*:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5435 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Comment: When you upgrade the server, you might also want to upgrade your client. And you have to use the new client, not the old one.

Comment: 1) To your question **add as text** the container software you are using and where you are getting the Postgres image. 2) Is `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12 postgresql-server-dev-12` being done in the container of the host? 3) To you question add the output of `pg_lsclusters `.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) added. i used docker and i specified the version. 2) yes it's done in the container 3) added. as it turned out it was the problem with the client. thanks for reaching out.